# How to get an argument in test.ts

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to test a particular component on the click of a button. For that i need to pass the name of component in my test.ts. I am trying to pass the argument through @Input but that not working.

I have tried with `@input` but not helpful

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
   BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
   platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

const context = require.context('./', true, /defualt-ammenu-list.component\.spec\.ts$/);

context.keys().map(context);
```

I expect the output that a variable name instead of /default-ammenu-list in require.context